# Select the ROW having the Maximum Value of a certain Column

Tags: mysql

For example, if my query returns two rows or more, I would like to **select the row having the most recent date.**

I'm doing something like this:

`SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Name=Mark AND MAX(TIMESTAMP(date(str_to_date(DATE_REGISTERED,'%d/%m/%Y'))))`

The error returned is: 
**#1111 - Invalid use of group function**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the order by statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Name=Mark
order by str_to_date(DATE_REGISTERED,'%d/%m/%Y') DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 2):

To limit your results to only the most recent (based on a field named DATE_REGISTERED as per your example) you would do

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Name='Mark' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(DATE_REGISTERED,'%d/%m/%Y')  DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: +1 . . . But you should change the query to be `order by date_registered` since that is the example in the question and put quotes around `Mark` so the syntax is correct.

Comment: but order by date_registered will sort the rows alphabetically i guess